# Query to compare columns in multiple tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables with similar columns and the same primary key, let's call them tables T1, T2 and T3.
The tables don't have the exact same number of columns, but some columns exist in all 3 tables.

I want to be able to, given the table names for T1, T2 and T3:

1. list all columns from (T1+T2+T3)
2. for each column, I want to see:

   - if they exist or not for each table
   - if they exist, their values(*)
   - a comparison of their values in each table(*)

(*) for a specific record

Something like below, where "-" means that the column doesn't exist for that table:

```
Column         T1     T2     T3      Comparison
-------        ----   ----   ----    ----------
C1             "A"    "A"    "A"     EQUAL
C2             -      "B"    "B"     DIFFERENT
C3             "C"    null   "C"     DIFFERENT
C4             "D"    "E"    "F"     DIFFERENT
C5             -      "G"     -      DIFFERENT
C6             null   null    null   EQUAL
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: T1/C1 = "A" means *all* rows in T1 have the same value in column C1, namely the string 'A'? This is certainly a rare case. Normally there would be many different values in a column. Is this what `null` represents?

Comment: Yes ... but ... you could query the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` dictionary table for the entries for those tables to get a list of columns .... then you could join that to compare the columns across tables and `PIVOT` that to get it into your format .... then you would need dynamic SQL to compare the values - how do you expect to perform the comparison assuming there are multiple rows in each table?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I forgot to mention that the values shown in the example are for a specific record. I edited the original question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve the first part for you. This will mark with an 'X' if the column exist in each table.

```
select column_name
      ,max(case when owner = 'schema' and table_name = 'T1' then 'X' end) as t1
      ,max(case when owner = 'schema' and table_name = 'T2' then 'X' end) as t2
      ,max(case when owner = 'schema' and table_name = 'T3' then 'X' end) as t3
  from all_tab_columns
 where (owner = 'schema' and table_name = 'T1')
    or (owner = 'schema' and table_name = 'T2')
    or (owner = 'schema' and table_name = 'T3')
 group 
    by column_name;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronnis, this does solve part of the problem!